# How to measure memory usage of command in powershell

Tags: performance, powershell, memory, profiling

How can I measure memory usage of a command in powershell. I'm thinking something like "Maximum resident memory" GNU `time` returns with `-v` flag. `Measure-Command` only measures time.

I also found this in my searches https://communary.net/2014/10/28/measure-scriptblock/ but its method for measuring memory use is clearly broken. It ouputs 0 kB for programs that definitely use a few megabytes.

My experience of shell scripting is mostly with bash, unfortunately. I found a few solutions that output the momentary memory use of a process using powershell. I tried using `Start-Job`, but running my same command inside Start-Job seems to kill it right away (It's an exe in the local directory). And anyway, I'm interested in total memory use by the process, not the momentary use at a point in time.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for processes memory usage -- or memory usage of a function in your script?

Check out [Get-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-7.1)
It returns [System.Diagnostics.Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-5.0#properties) which have a bunch of properties related to memory usage. The link you had is using the same class.

He's also using `[gc]` the garbage collector, to try to force memory to be collected early. If you're not testing it's own process, you can skip that. Spawning a child to measure might be more reliable.

Comment: Is there a way to run an executable in the local directory and get-process on that?

Comment: I figured out my mistake. Powershell, unlike unix shells, seems to run start-job from home directory, so I added `-Init ([ScriptBlock]::Create("Set-Location '$pwd'"))` to it.

Comment: Powershell added the parameter [`-WorkingDirectory` for that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-7#parameters)